# ExecuteNonQuery() Not Updating the database

Tags: c#

I saw the same topic/question in various posts here, but none seem to be what i am searching for. 
I have 2 identical tables in a database, and i want to populate them in an identical way, with two identical methods, they only have different data storing. The first method `EnterParams` works fine & populates the table, but the second one fails. 
Tried debugging the code line by line and when it goes to `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` it catches an exception `(In my controller i have a try/catch method)` and it stops.

How can i know what exception it is and how to handle it? It is weird because both methods are identical, one succeeds and one fails

```
namespace Test.Models
{

public class ArduinoEntities : DbContext 
{
    public ArduinoEntities()
        : base("name=ArduinoEntities")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TempHum> TempHum { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TempHum2> TempHum2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}

[Table("TempHum")]
public class TempHum
{
    [Key]
    public long SID { get; set; }   
    public string Humidity { get; set; }
    public string TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string LightLevel { get; set; }
    public string Dust { get; set; }      
}

public class EnterParams
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArduinoEntities"].ConnectionString);
    TempHum Emp = new TempHum();

    public string AddParams(TempHum Emp)
    {
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertData", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Humidity", Emp.Humidity);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemperatureC", Emp.TemperatureC);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LightLevel", Emp.LightLevel);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dust", Emp.Dust);

        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return "";
    }
}

[Table("TempHum2")]
public class TempHum2
{
    [Key]
    public long SID { get; set; }
    public string Humidity { get; set; }
    public string TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string LightLevel { get; set; }
    public string Dust { get; set; }
}

public class EnterParams2
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArduinoEntities"].ConnectionString);
    TempHum2 Emp = new TempHum2();

    public string AddParams2(TempHum2 Emp)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("InsertData2", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Humidity", Emp.Humidity);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TemperatureC", Emp.TemperatureC);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LightLevel", Emp.LightLevel);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dust", Emp.Dust);

        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return "";

       }
      }
    }
```

The "InsertData2" stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData2]
@SID int,
@Humidity VARCHAR(50),
@TemperatureC VARCHAR(50),
@LightLevel VARCHAR(50),
@Dust VARCHAR(50)
AS
begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempHum2] ([Humidity],[TemperatureC],[LightLevel],[Dust]) VALUES (@Humidity,@TemperatureC,@LightLevel,@Dust)
end
```

Comment: Including `@SID` the procedure `InsertData2`[very poor name] expects `5` params but you have passed only `4`

Comment: In your `Exception Settings` in Visual Studio mark all `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` this probably give you some more information about the exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: When debugging, stop in your exception handler and *examine* the exception.  The exception object contains information about the error, including a message and a stack trace.

Comment: @David did it and the problem is that i am passing a NULL value to SID column and it doesn't allow nulls

Comment: @un-lucky i deleted it from the store procedure and i get the same exception/error

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: @un-lucky  Cannot insert the value `NULL` into column `'SID'`, table 'Arduino.dbo.TempHum2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

Comment: So then what is the question? The exception message has already told you what is wrong.

Comment: @E.Hysenaj That exception information really needs to be in your question to help us answer your question quicker and more accurately.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen being a beginner, didnt know how to see what the exception was and how to handle it, but the comments and answer below helped me find out everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering based on the comments, you can choose either one from the following:

- Make the column `SID` as Auto Increment, then you need not to insert value to this column.
- Include `SID` in your query and pass the value for `SID` through command param

Comment: Thank you a lot, when creating the table i had missed making the column `SID` as Auto Increment, just did it and it worked.

Comment: @E.Hysenaj: Good to hear that it's worked... HAppy coding!